# How can I get the iframe src?

Tags: python, selenium

its iframe code

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" class="blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post" frameborder="0" height="66px" id="result" name="result" src="www.rom.net/result/14545" width="100%" style="display: block;" data-resized="true" xpath="1"></iframe>
```

its my code

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#result'))).click()
adres1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='result']").get_attribute('src')
```

I want to get src link inside iframe

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get value of src

```
url = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='result']").get_attribute("src");
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Chrome' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'